# How to render variable stored DOM Nodes on VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, opentok, tokbox

I'm using Tokbox, a WebRTC SDK and one of their methods returns a `video` object into a variable.

With Vanilla JS I'd simply use append to add it to my DOM, but with VueJS, I'm not sure how can I accomplish this. I tried using `v-html` but it outputs the object as a JSON. Here is a screenshot of the object representation on chrome's console:

[image]

I don't want to use vanilla JS to append it, I'd rather expect VueJS to convert it to its own Virtual DOM object so I can freely manipulate it and don't worry about wrong states for this object.

I don't know if I'm making sense over here, but I hope you get the idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use $refs, something like

```
<video ref="tokboxVideo" />
```

then

```
mounted() {
    this.$refs.tokboxVideo.srcObject = this.tokboxVideoElementCreated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better success with the `streamCreated` event on the session. Create a `Subscriber` component like below:

```js
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import OT from '@opentok/client';
export default {
  name: 'subscriber',
  props: {
    stream: {
      type: OT.Stream,
      required: true
    },
    session: {
      type: OT.Session,
      required: true
    },
    opts: {
      type: Object,
      required: false
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {

    const subscriber = this.session.subscribe(
      this.stream,
      this.$el,
      this.opts,
      err => {
        if (err) {
          this.$emit('error', err);
        } else {
          this.$emit('subscriberConnected', subscriber);
        }
      }
    );
    this.$emit('subscriberCreated', subscriber);
  }
};
</script>
```

This will insert the video element inside the component. Then you can control how the component is displayed in your app.

Check out the [basic vue sample](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Vue-Basic-Video-Chat) in our repos.